# Falco crashes in aws ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, falco

I am trying to run the docker container in ECS when I do that I get the following error.
the task definitions https://github.com/sysdiglabs/falco-aws-firelens-integration/blob/master/ecs/falco/task-definition.json but modified it to take the latest `"image": "falcosecurity/falco:latest"`

I even tried logging into the instance and ran the docker command

```
docker run -i -t --name falco --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /boot:/host/boot:ro -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro falcosecurity/falco:latest
```

I go the same error.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for falcosecurity/falco:latest
* Setting up /usr/src links from host
* Running falco-driver-loader with: driver=module, compile=yes, download=yes
* Unloading falco module, if present
* Trying to dkms install falco module
* Running dkms build failed, couldn't find /var/lib/dkms/falco/96bd9bc560f67742738eb7255aeb4d03046b8045/build/make.log
* Trying to load a system falco driver, if present
* Trying to find locally a prebuilt falco module for kernel 4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64, if present
Detected an unsupported target system, please get in touch with the Falco community
2020-05-29T17:27:28+0000: Falco initialized with configuration file /etc/falco/falco.yaml
2020-05-29T17:27:28+0000: Loading rules from file /etc/falco/falco_rules.yaml:
2020-05-29T17:27:28+0000: Loading rules from file /etc/falco/falco_rules.local.yaml:
2020-05-29T17:27:28+0000: Loading rules from file /etc/falco/k8s_audit_rules.yaml:
2020-05-29T17:27:29+0000: Unable to load the driver. Exiting.
2020-05-29T17:27:29+0000: Runtime error: error opening device /host/dev/falco0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the falco module is loaded.. Exiting.
```

**OS Details**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-xxxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
[ec2-user@ip-172-xxxx-xxx-xxx  ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Falco maintainer here.

There are multiple reasons causing that error:

- your host does not have the Linux kernel headers (needed by Falco to compile a Falco driver suitable for your Amazon Linux 2 4.14.173-137.229 kernel)
- when the compilation of the driver fails, Falco looks for a prebuilt driver for your host's kernel
- the Falco version you were using didn't have a prebuilt for that kernel, unfortunately

In fact, in order to work, Falco needs a driver (there are two main drivers: a kernel module and an eBPF one). For this reason, the Falco container needs to be privileged: to the driver on the host where you're running the Falco container.

**Solutions**

So, how to solve this issue and get Falco running?

Some options here:

- install the kernel headers (package kernel-devel) on your Amazon Linux 2 host
- update to a newer Falco:
  recent Falco versions ships ~4K prebuilt drivers, also the [one](https://download.falco.org/driver/13ec67ebd23417273275296813066e07cb85bc91/falco_amazonlinux2_4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64_1.ko) you were - at that time - unable to find